# How to get specific object from Stream using Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I just read about `Serialization/Deserialization` with `BinaryFormatter (SoapFormatter)` and wrote a little code to check behavior of this processes:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "ListA-0", "ListA-1" };
    private static List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "ListB-0", "ListB-1" };
    private static List<string> listC = new List<string>() { "ListC-0", "ListC-1" };

    private static void SaveApplicationState(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, listA);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, listB);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, listC);
    }

    private static void LoadApplicationState(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        listA = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        listB = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        listC = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    private static void ShowList(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);

        foreach (var str in listA.Union(listB).Union(listC))
            Console.WriteLine(str);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ShowList("Before save: ");

            SaveApplicationState(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            LoadApplicationState(ms);

            ShowList("After load: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Both results are similar and (order of deserialized objects):

```
Before save:
ListA-0
ListA-1
ListB-0
ListB-1
ListC-0
ListC-1
After load:
ListA-0
ListA-1
ListB-0
ListB-1
ListC-0
ListC-1
```

But i have a question (sorry if it's stupid or incorrect) with this behavior.

If i add new `List<int>`:

```
private static List<int> list0 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
```

and `Serialize` it at start of `Stream`:

```
formatter.Serialize(stream, list0);
formatter.Serialize(stream, listA);
formatter.Serialize(stream, listB);
formatter.Serialize(stream, listC);
```

but try to `Deserialize` with wrong order:

```
listA = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
list0 = (List<int>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
listB = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
listC = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

I'll get exception with `casting` and i understand why it's so.

So, is it possible to get specific object from `Stream` (for example, if i know this `type` or any other `properties`) or i have to `Deserialize` stream until end and get every object in order they were `Serialized`?

Comment: You need to move the stream to the beginning of where the object is stored. You may need to store some metadata for that.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?